# How can I simplify this LINQ query that searches for keywords in strings and orders them by relevance?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Let's say I have some `MyObject`s and each of them have a `Description` property. I have a list of keywords that I want to use to search through the `MyObject` list. I want to order them in descending order, by the number of keywords that each of their `Description` contains.

Sample input (only showing the `Description` property, note the initial order):

```
"Foo Bar"
"Foo Boo"
"Bar Bar"
```

Sample keywords:

```
"Boo", "Foo"
```

Sample output (only showing the `Description` property, note the final order):

```
"Foo Boo" (matches 2 keywords)
"Foo Bar" (matches 1 keyword)
```

"Bar" "Bar" is not in the results because it matches 0 keywords.

I am currently using this very complicated chain of methods:

```
return keywords.SelectMany(
    x => MyObjects.Where(y => y.Description.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(x.ToLowerInvariant()))
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
    .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

As you can see, I am first selecting on `keywords`. I think that as a reader of the code, you would expect to see some transformations to be done on `MyObjects` first. Usually when I write LINQ I try to visualize in my head what the operations will look like. Seeing the keywords being transformed just feels counter-intuitive. I also don't like the nested query in `SelectMany` because it makes the query syntax look very ugly:

```
var query = from keyword in keywords
            from matchedObjects in (from obj in MyObjects where obj.Description.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(keyword.ToLowerInvariant()) select obj)
            group matchedObjects by matchedObjects into sameObjects
            orderby sameObjects.Count() descending
            select sameObjects.Key;
return query.ToList();
```

How can I improve the LINQ query? Ideally:

- no nested queries
- starts with `MyObjects.SomeLINQOperation...` instead of `keywords`.

I would expect there is an easier/more intuitive way because this seems like a trivial thing to do, but I would also accept that there is no easier way if an explanation is provided.

Comment: What do you consider an "improvement"? Faster code? Shorder code? Less memory-consuming code? As it is the question is quiute opnion-based and attracts many different answers striving for different measurements. Apart from this question about working code should go to [codereview.stackechange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @HimBromBeere see the two bullet points? That’s what I want, nothing to do with speed. I don’t think it’s opinion based because those two points are pretty objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
    var objects = new[]{
                    new MyObject{Description = "Foo Bar"},
                    new MyObject{Description = "Foo Boo"},
                    new MyObject{Description = "Foo Bee"},
                    new MyObject{Description = "Bar Bee"},
                    new MyObject{Description = "Boo Bee"},
                };
                var keywords = new[] { "Foo", "Bar" };
                var results = objects
                    .GroupBy(x => keywords.Where(
                                          keyword => x.Description.Contains(keyword) 
                                          ).Count()
                    )
                    .Where(x => x.Key > 0) // discard no matches
//                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()) // order by mathing objects count
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
//                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray())
                     .Select(x => new {Count = x.Key, Objects = x.ToArray()}).ToList(); // or create anonymous type
                    ;
```

It groups objects by matches count, discards no matches and puts the most matches on the top

Comment: Tbh I don't need how many keywords are matched, so probably `SelectMany(x => x)` will work, right?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, it should

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
results = myObjects.OrderByDescending(myObject => keywords.Where(keyword => myObject.Description.Contains(keyword)).Count());
```

Give you what you need?

EDIT:

```
var temp = myObjects.Where(myObject => keywords.Any(keyword => myObject.Description.Contains(keyword)))
            .OrderByDescending(myObject => keywords.Where(keyword => myObject.Description.Contains(keyword)).Count());
```

Not sure if this counts as 'better' or not.

Comment: Missed the part about filtering out MyObjects with no keywords. Edited my answer.

Comment: That fulfils one of my wants +1 :) Will accept if no one else posts something better or an explanation why both can't be simultaneously fulfilled.